# XML format-number problems when using separators

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

We're working on a web page that should be able to display prices such that spaces are the grouping separators and commas are the decimal separators. For example, the value `1234567.89` should display as `1 234 567,89`.  (We're actually using `&#160;` so we get a non-breaking space.)

This seems like the right XSL to do it, and it almost works, but I get a "." character after the rest of it.  So I end up with 
`"1 234 567,89."`
instead of 
`"1 234 567,89"`.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
xmlns:hsi="http://www.myfakecompany.com/fakey" 
extension-element-prefixes="msxsl hsi">

    <xsl:decimal-format name="euro" 
        decimal-separator="," 
        grouping-separator="&#160;"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(1234567.89, '#&#160;###.##;(#&#160;###.##)', 'euro')"/>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format string is applied after the decimal separator is set, so you need to change it to:

```
'#&#160;###,##;(#&#160;###,##)'
```

I.e. with commas instead of periods.